# MySQL: get records from database and add a COUNT() column to the rows

Tags: mysql, join, count

I'm trying to retrieve books from one table and left join the chapters table. What I need from the second table is just the COUNT() of chapters available for those books and add that value as an extra column called chapters (or something else).

My current try looks like this:
SELECT b.*, count(c.chapter_nr) as chapters FROM `books` as b left join chapters as c on c.book_id = b.id

This only gets one from from the books table and adds the count() result to that row, but I'd like to get ALL the rows from the books table, hence the LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.*, count(c.chapter_nr) as chapters 
FROM books as b 
LEFT JOIN chapters as c on (c.book_id = b.id)
GROUP BY b.id
```

### EXPLANATION

You need to group by the book in order to determine the actual chapter counts. If you were to leave out the GROUP BY clause, you would be retrieving a resultset of all chapters of every book.  You simply want to limit the results to unique books and their corresponding chapter counts.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT b.*, count(c.chapter_nr) as chapters 
FROM books AS b 
LEFT JOIN chapters AS c ON c.book_id = b.id 
GROUP BY b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
SELECT b.*,  
(select count(*) from chapters c where c.book_id = b.id) as chapters   
FROM books b
```

This will return 0 if there are no chapters for a book.

Comment: The problem with the left outer join methods is that they will tend to return a minimum count of 1, even if there are no chapter rows

Comment: With the left outer join methods, as long as you count a non-nullable attribute of chapters (like `chapter_nr`), you will get a count of 0 for a book with no chapters.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you need a "group by" clause to do what you want:

```
Select b.*, count(*) as chapters
from books b left outer join chapters c
on c.book_id = b.id
group by b.*
```

Comment: This will return 1 as the number of chapters for books that have no chapters. Change `count(*)` to `count(c.chapter_nr)` to count the number of chapters (rows with a non-null `chapter_nr`).